# How to add an additional View to generated Scaffold and adding an action to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hey all I am building out a CAD App in Rails 4 Ruby 2

I apologize if this is a noob question but i'm hung up here..

> **BACKGROUND**

I have my main index page, acting as a multi view dispatch window, currently it Shows Active Pending and Cleared Calls. What I want to add now is a secondary page to list calls with a status of active and that I can eventually add some search fields to to look up previous calls.

**my current calls_controller.rb index looks like:**

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'ACTIVE'}
    @pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'PENDING'}
    @clear_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'CLEAR'}
    @approved_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == "APPROVED"}
  end

**I HAVE THEN ADDED**

  def histroy
    @calls = Call.all
    @approved_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == "APPROVED"}
  end
```

**I have added a view to the scaffold views and named that view history.hmtl.erb as shown below**:

[image]

My routes.rb looks like

```
  resources :calls do
    collection do
      get 'history'
    end
  end
```

**I then created button to access the the new view:**

```
      <%= link_to history_calls_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-nav", id: 'home-btn' do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search"> Call History</i>
      <% end %>
```

**When I click the button to access the page i get the following error:**

```
NoMethodError in Calls#history
undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass --> There are already calls with that status but it should return 0 if there are no approved calls

Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6

  <div class="panel panel-warning" id="clr-calls-pnl">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Call History -- TOTAL CLEARED CALLS <span class="badge"><%= @approved_calls.length %></span></h4></center></div>
    <table class="table" id="approve-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><center>Call Number</center></th>
```

Any help here would be much appreciated as i am still a bit of a noob but have never done this sort of thing before.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1:**

I changed it to the .try(:lenght)

and now I get this:

```
NoMethodError in Calls#history
Showing /Users/TaurenLTD1/Desktop/TaurenLabs/PatrolProCAD/PatProCadApp/app/views/calls/history.html.erb where line #31 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #31):
29
30
31
32
33
34


      <tbody>
        <% @approved_calls.each do |call| %>
        <tr>
          <td><center><%= call.call_number %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.site_id %></center></td>
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
This is what the rails log is showing when I Open the History Page:

Started GET "/calls/history" for ::1 at 2015-11-21 19:46:55 -0700
Processing by CallsController#history as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered calls/history.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 129.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: See Edit #1 At Bottom of Question. Its almost like its not talking to the model.. i can add the entire controller if you want?

Comment: This all worked on the index.html.erb page.

Comment: Again, your `@approved_calls` is `nil` and thats the issue. 
Could you check why it's not populating in the controller action?
Also, to prevent this error, you can add a condition like this:`<% if @approved_calls.present?%>` then loop through them, if not then show a message that there are no approved calls to show.

Comment: Also, in your controller try this: `@approved_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == "APPROVED"} || []` this will ensure that, your `@approved_calls` won't be `nil`, if it can't find anything, it should be an empty array. Try this and let me know.

Comment: Ok so i added the if approved_calls.present to the page.. however it is still not finding call with the status of approved there is already one with that status. The @approved_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == "APPROVED"} is already in the controller under def history as shown in the original post above. however i can at least see the page now

Comment: use `@approved_calls = Call.where(status: 'APPROVED')` in your controller. and then try again.

Comment: Still returns a blank screen, so its not seeing the status of Approved. with your latest controller action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95823/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-shawn-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) here.

Change:

```
<%= @approved_calls.length %>
```

To:

```
<%= @approved_calls.try(:length) %>
```

For some reason your `@approved_calls` is `nil` and that's why you got that error. The above should prevent you from getting that error. But, a better approach would be to see why `@approved_calls` is getting `nil` value and fix that part and make sure you populate `@approved_calls` instance variable.

#### Update

Change your `history` action to this:

```
  def history
    @approved_calls = Call.where(status: 'APPROVED')
  end
```

#### Final Update

You actually have a typo in your controller action. Change `histroy` to `history`.

Comment: Ok so i added the if approved_calls.present to the page.. however it is still not finding call with the status of approved there is already one with that status.  The @approved_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == "APPROVED"} is already in the controller under def history as shown in the original post above. however i can at least see the page now

Comment: You have to make sure you have calls with `status: 'APPROVED'` in your database, Then it should definitely work. Try creating calls with `status: 'APPROVED'`: `Call.create(status: 'APPROVED')` from your rails console and then try again.

Comment: So I Followed that created it in the console and it created.. but still not appearing in the view

Comment: What do you see if you do: `Call.where(status: 'APPROVED')` in your rails console?

Comment: when i do that i see Call with the id of 3 and 9 return successfully.

Comment: put: `puts @approved_calls.inspect` in your controller action and see if it gets printed. If it's present in the database, then it really should work.

Comment: It dose not return anything

Comment: Then, its not getting the data from the same database. Verify that. Also, re-starting your app and the computer if possible. Because, I dont see any issue here.

Comment: Ok ill try a computer restart

Comment: still nothing after a system restart

Comment: pretty sure you are not pointing to the correct database then.

Comment: check your `database.yml` file and make sure your app is using the same database that has all those data that you created from your rails console.

Comment: its in my Calls Controller, same controller the Scaffold generator created.

Comment: do you have your project on github or somewhere so that I can take a look locally?

Comment: yes give me a few min ill commit what ive done and ill post it up there and shoot you the link

Comment: https://github.com/swilson223/PatProCad Is the linnk to my Git Thanks much for looking at this!

Comment: oh man! you got a typo :( change `histroy` to `history` in your controller

Comment: and that fixed it! Wow i feel like a total tool here! thank you so much for your help here! i really do appreciate it!